# Ruby on Rails 3: How to access current_user within model

Tags: model, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an Activities model that acts as sort of a dashboard for the entire rails app I have. I have some :after_create callbacks passing the Customer object and a generic message into the Activity model to store the information. This works fine and dandy by outputting "has created customer Microsoft in the Toolbox." but I can't seem to figure out how to get current_user provided by Devise into the model so I can show which user created the Customer object.

I've thought about doing virtual attributes but I was hoping there was a better way to do this. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: There's lots of questions on SO for this. Please search for the terms `current_user model`